# Having trouble getting commas in my numbers

Tags: ruby, regex

I did some searching around and found a few things that looked like they might work, but none did for me. The best one i found was this - `/\G([+-]?\d+?)(?=(?:\d{3})++(?=\.\d++$|$))/g`
After trying to use this it didn't work for me :(. My code is...

```
text =IO.read(ARGV[0])

text.gsub!(/\G([+-]?\d+?)(?=(?:\d{3})++(?=\.\d++$|$))/g, '\1,')

$stdout.print text
```

http://regex101.com/r/bA9cV2#pcre

I'm new to regex so sorry in advance if I made some bad mistakes, but what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Nix the trailing `g` in your regex and you're good to go:

```
irb(main):003:0> text="123456789"
=> "123456789"
irb(main):004:0> text.gsub!(/\G([+-]?\d+?)(?=(?:\d{3})++(?=\.\d++$|$))/, '\1,')
=> "123,456,789"
```